# Can we change array stored in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a product filter array which i stored in redux, initially its an empty array and i want to dispatching an object in it one by one .

The issue is i want to check if the `object_id` is already is in the array then i don't want to dispatch it and as well as delete that particular object in redux state.

Likewise,
if user added blue color filter so its accept but if user again added blue color filter so its shouldn't dispatch this object and also remove this object in redux.

**reducer:**

```
filterd :[]

const filterreducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  
  switch (action.type) {
   
    case ADD_FILTER:
        return {
            ...state,
            filterd :[...state.filterd,action.payload] 
        };
  
    default:
        return state;
 }
}
export default filterreducer ;
```

Comment: You can use xor (check lodash) with individual filters, it will add or remove a filter depending on if its already present or not

Answer (score 0):

```
initialState ={
  filterd :[]
}

const filterreducer = (state = initialState, action) => { switch (action.type) {

    case ADD_FILTER:
        return {
            ...state,
            filterd :action.paylod 
        };
  
    default:
        return state;
}
}

 export default filterreducer ;
```

you have to store response data in payload while dispatching that action
such as:

```
dispatch({
   type:ADD_FILTER,
   payload: response.data
)
```